# Is 'Single Sitting' a proper phrase?

Tags: grammar, phrases, subcontinental-english

Being an Indian, I don't like the way we Indians use the English. Of course I also make mistakes, but I will try to learn from time to time.
I see and hear some phrases like, *Please do the needful*, *Years back* etc which are absolute blunders, I was wondering if *Single Sitting* is also Indian made ;)?
(Actually I am pretty sure it is Indian made :D ) Generally we hear this phrase as in http://goo.gl/y3gl06.

By *Single Sitting* we Indians mean the job attached to this phrase can be done in single visit.

Comment: Why would you see typical Indian expressions as “absolute blunders”? I wonder how many Americans see _drugstore_ as a blunder, just because the Brits don't use the word. _Indian English_ is just another dialect of English, like American, British, Australian or South-African English. Furthermore, it is probably the fastest-growing and in a while possibly the largest English dialect. With gems like _prepone_ and _thrice_, I'm quite enamoured by it.

Comment: @oerkelens - "thrice" is new?

Comment: In the US, we do use the phrase "in a single sitting", but usually only applied it to meals: "He ate the whole pizza. In a single sitting!". I've personally never heard it applied to a job or work in general.

Comment: _Please do the needful_ was pretty common in the UK (and I presume the US), years back. Single sitting, likewise, but single sitting is probably still in common use. One could get all one's teeth removed in a single sitting back then.

Comment: @LittleEva: _thrice_ is, alas, deemed archaic in most English dialects, as far as I am aware. I for one got repeatedly corrected by my teachers when insisting on using it, but it is just so much more elegant than _three times_ :)

Comment: Also, "Please do the needful" and "Years back" make sense to me without much effort. What does "prepone" signify?

Comment: @oerkelens I am surprised that you like Indian dialect, but people here are just doing a straight translation than knowing the correct usage.

Comment: @oerkelens There's a *big* difference between InE and dialects like AusE, BrE, AmE, etc: speakers of those latter dialects have English as a first (and frequently *only*) language; speakers of InE overwhelmingly have it as a second (or third, fourth), and typically only use it in a specific (work) context, as opposed to a day-to-day language in the home. That said, I agree with you that "*Do the needful*" isn't a blunder: it's an abomination.

Comment: You're intent on learning the language well so that you sound "native", Sree, that's probably why some of the "anglicisms" bother you.

Comment: There is a difference between _Indian English_, which is an English dialect, and so-called _Hinglish_, which is an ad-hoc mixture of English and (mostly) Hindi. Expressions like _do the needful_, _as per your request_, _thrice_, and, I suspect, _single sitting_ are perfectly fine English, even if they may seem dated to speakers of other dialects.

Comment: @DanBron: there are more and more native speakers of InE, and according to for instance David Crystal, InE will become in the 21st century what AmE was in the 20th and BrE in the 19th. It may at the moment be less clearly defined than some other dialects, but discarding it, as the OP does, as a collection of "blunders" seems linguistically unjustified.

Comment: @LittleEva _prepone_ means to bring forward in time (Thursday's meeting has been preponed to Wednesday) and the modern use was coined by an American about a century ago.

Comment: "In a single sitting" might be used to describe, eg, how dental work was done, or, being more literal, a photo session.  (A formal photo session is typically called a "sitting".)  It may have fallen out of use (I don't recall hearing it recently), but it's certainly familiar to me and wouldn't sound at all odd to my ear, when used in the right context.

Comment: What is a "proper phrase?" Nothing's improper with this phrase. AFAIK, *single sitting* is an adjective + gerund (noun) phrase, not a set phrase. And probably nothing geographic about it.

Comment: I can't see any reason for this question to be tagged *Indian English*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outside of India, *single sitting* is and was certainly used, as attested in the comments, but it will nowadays usually refer to a meal.

The (extended) meaning of *in the time frame of a single occurrence* **may** be typical Indian usage currently, but I would certainly not qualify such usage as a “blunder”, let alone an “absolute” one.

It is no more a blunder than an American calling a pharmacy a *drug store*!

Comment: What the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I was considering downvoting for saying "will usually refer to a meal," but I didn't.  There's no reason at all to consider the expression "Indian".

Comment: @HotLicks: I referred loosely to DanBron's comment under the question, but I edited in your correct observation that earlier use of the expression was similar in meaning to the current Indian usage. The expression was indeed not Indian, but it's current usage in the way described by the OP probably _is_.

Comment: It's true that *sitting* in this sense is defined in the context of a legislative or a judicial "session," which meaning is carried further to any official session and thereon to any session in general. *Single* is **merely an adjective, "single sitting" not being a set phrase**. The phrase is also common in the context of appearing for an examination or a doctor's appointment.

Comment: "I couldn't put down the new Neal Stephenson novel and read it in a single sitting."

Comment: @Kris I disagree; I think "in a single sitting" is an idiomatic phrase.  It derives from logical pieces, but we don't use "sitting" that way anymore except with "single".

Comment: @Joe "We"=? Research the word and phrase :)

Answer (score 11):

> **Single sitting** (in **InE**) is commonly used in context of -single sitting treatment-situations:
>
> - Hair replacement procedures
> - Root canal Tx
> - Cataract operation
> - etc.

It's probably an adoption from the idiom "at/in one sitting".

> **[at/in one sitting](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+one+sitting)**:  If you do something at one sitting, you do it during one period of time without stopping.
>    -  *I read the whole book in one sitting.* 
>   (TFD)

Some common **InE** phrases that you may come accross are:

> - Let us discuss *about* politics
> - What is your *good* name?
> - Let’s order for a pizza
> - I am not at home, I’m out of station
> - He returned it back to me
> - I am here only
> - etc.

Comment: Indians have intentionally and unintentionally customized English to better suit their needs. and of course the translations from Hindi to English bring about phrases such as "Good name"..."subh naam" or auspicious name.

Comment: Out of station ~= Out of pocket?

Comment: What the heck is a "good name"?

Answer (score 1):

- Amusing it may sound to the natives, single sitting is used to
  decribe even one night stands.

> Indians will often ask, "What is your good name?" which is a somewhat
>   literal translation of "Aapka shubh naam kya hai?"

Shubh means  auspicious or good, and it is basically used as a **polite way of asking  for someone's full name.**

> Something which Indian English has that is not found in other
>   varieties of English is the use of **only** (@MystiSinha- I am here
>   only) and **itself** to emphasize time and place.

It comes from the Hindi word "hee" and produces sentences like "I was in Toledo only/itself".